# ZF2 passing arguments to factories at runtime

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

In ZF2, I have a factory for a multicheckbox (simplified)

```
class MultiCheckboxFactory
{
    public function __invoke(FormElementManager $formElementManager)
    {
        $multiCheck = new MultiCheckbox();

        $serviceManager = $formElementManager->getServiceLocator();
        $mapper = $serviceManager->get('Path\To\The\Mapper\SomeMapper');
        $resultFromQuery = $mapper->findText('text');

        // further setting up of the multicheckbox based on $resultFromQuery

        return $multiCheck;
    }
}
```

I want the multicheckbox to render different content depending on `$resultFromQuery` that comes from the mapper's `findText()` method.

I thought of passing a variable to the `__invoke(FormElementManager $formElementManager, $someText)`. But the problem is that when I call the multicheckbox from the service manager like this:

```
$element = $formElementManager->get('Path\To\Factory\Alias\Multicheckbox');
```

I don't see how to pass an additional variable. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `MutableCreationOptionsInterface`, this allows your factory to receive runtime options which you pass through the serviceManager `get()` method.

```
use Zend\ServiceManager\MutableCreationOptionsInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\MutableCreationOptionsTrait;

class MultiCheckboxFactory implements MutableCreationOptionsInterface
{
    use MutableCreationOptionsTrait;

    public function __invoke(FormElementManager $formElementManager)
    {
        $options = $this->getCreationOptions();

        var_dump($options);

        $multiCheck = new MultiCheckbox();

        ....
    }
}
```

Now you can pass options:

```
$element = $formElementManager->get('Path\To\Factory\Alias\Multicheckbox', ['foo' => 'bar']);
```

Comment: +1 for `use MutableCreationOptionsTrait;`: now i don't have to write the accessors for the `$createOptions`.

Answer (score 2):

Update: `MutableCreationOptionsTrait` is no longer available in ZF3: https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-servicemanager/migration/#miscellaneous-interfaces-traits-and-classes

The simplest way to do this now appears to be

```
$element = $formElementManager->build('Path\To\Factory\Alias\Multicheckbox', ['foo' => 'bar']);
```

though this will give you a discrete (not shared) instance every time.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response. As I understand it: "shared" is the default. So a regular $container->get('whatever') call gets you a shared instance, but for that very reason, you can't pass it any constructor options as you can with build().